# Error When Defining Relationships In sequelize-typescript On nestjs/sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm getting an error

> No overload matches this call

Whenever I try to use @HasMany() or @BelongsTo decorators.
I'm using nestjs/sequelize: "^0.2.0", sequelize: "^6.4.0", and sequelize-typescript: "^2.0.0"

I'm probably missing something trivial, but this could also be an issue with the versioning or the integration between these three libraries. It probably has nothing to do with nestjs, but I think it's worth mentioning just in case.

Here are my two models:

user.model.ts

```
import {
  AllowNull,
  Column,
  DataType,
  HasMany,
  HasOne,
  IsEmail,
  Model,
  Table,
  Unique,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Course } from '../courses/course.model';
import { UserRole } from './enums/user.roles.enum';


@Table
export class User extends Model<User> {
  @Column
  firstName: string;

  @Column
  lastName: string;

  @IsEmail
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Unique
  @Column
  email: string;

  @Column({ defaultValue: false })
  verified: boolean;

  @Column
  verificationCode: string;

  @Column
  passwordHash: string;

  
  @Column({ defaultValue: UserRole.STUDENT })
  role: string;

  @HasMany(() => Course)
  courses: Course[];
}
```

Course.model.ts

```
import {
  AllowNull,
  BelongsTo,
  Column,
  DataType,
  ForeignKey,
  HasOne,
  IsEmail,
  Model,
  Table,
  Unique,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { User } from '../users/user.model';
    
@Table
export class Course extends Model<Course> {
  @Unique
  @Column
  title: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column
  teacherId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
  @Column
  teacher: User;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved after following this [issue](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/issues/835)

Turns out to be related to sequelize@6.3.5 with both sequelize-typescript @1.1.0 & @2.0.0-beta.0

Can be worked around by downgrading to sequelize@6.1.1,
or removing `<Course>` and `<User>` types from the class declaration.

Also removing the `@Column` decorator from the teacher property in course, which was causing a different issue.